# what is the difference between git push origin HEAD : remote_branch and git push origin local_branch:remote_branch?

Tags: git, github, git-push

when I want to push the changes to remote repo branch,I need to run
`git push origin local_branch:remote_branch`
but it doesn't work sometimes
even get the error:src refspec local_branch does not match any.
run`git push origin HEAD:remote_branch`will work well
I want to know what the difference between these
Thanks!

reproduce my steps:

```
git checkout -b local_branch origin master

develop based on the local_branch...

git add .
git commit -m 'xxx'
git push origin HEAD:remote_branch  
//correct

git push origin local_branch:remote_branch
//error

git branch 
// can see local_branch
```

Comment: When you do the second version with `HEAD`, is your current branch `local_branch` or is it a different branch?

Comment: current branch local_branch

Comment: Note: `git checkout -b local_branch origin master` simply results in a peculiar error message: `fatal: 'master' is not a commit and a branch 'local_branch' cannot be created from it`. (`master` does name a commit, so this error message is wrong.) In any case I was not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I create the local_branch based on a origin branch from the origin repo.git clone the origin repo,git checkout -b local_branch origin origin_branch。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git push` command takes positional arguments:

`git push remote refspec`

(The `git fetch` command works similarly.)  Your question is about the *`refspec`* part.

A *refspec*, in Git, is essentially<sup>1</sup> a pair of names separated by a colon `:` character, so both `HEAD:name2` and `name1:name2` work.  For `git push`, the name on the left—`HEAD` or *`name1`*—must be a valid name in *your* repository, as Git will need to use that name to find a commit hash ID.  The name on the right—*`name2`*—will be sent over to the *other* Git, the one receiving your `git push` command.  Your Git will ask that other Git to set *its* name *`name2`*.

When you use `HEAD`—which almost always<sup>2</sup> represents a valid hash ID in your own repository—your Git will figure out which branch you are on,<sup>3</sup> and use that branch name to find the hash ID of the commit to send.  (To view which branch you're on, use `git branch` or `git status`, for instance.)

When you use a *`name1`* such as `local_branch`, this *must* already be a valid name in your own local Git repository.  It can be a branch name, or a tag name, or even some other kind of name, but usually it should be a branch name.  If `git branch` does not show `local_branch` as a branch name (and it's not a tag or some other name), you will get the error message you are seeing: `src refspec local_branch does not match any`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This glosses over a lot of important details, so that we can just concentrate on the two-names version here.  In particular refspecs begin with an optional plus sign, to set the *force* flag, and may use a raw hash ID, and/or omit the colon by using only one name, in some cases.

<sup>2</sup>The *name* `HEAD` itself is always valid, even in "detached HEAD" mode, but you can be on an *unborn branch*, in which case `HEAD` does not represent a commit yet.

<sup>3</sup>In "detached HEAD" mode, you are not on *any* branch.  Most users will only be in this mode during a conflicted rebase, though.

Comment: Thanks,bro! I understand. I have another question to ask,  I am sure that local_branch can be seen when I run  git branch. Why does it make an error? This is what confused me.

Comment: @LiJin: If you can reproduce the problem, and include the commands that reproduce it (see [mcve]), it's much easier to address that sort of question.

Comment: ok, I will add the commands to describe this problem in detail, thank you

Comment: I edit this question and reproduce my steps on git ,I'm very much obliged to you！